# I connected Firestore to bigquery but data doesn't show up a datasets

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I seated up a connection however Firestore Data data does not show up in BigQuery ? When i check a bigquery studio there nothing there of any datatable of my firebase project, i waiting almost 5 days.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viazV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B16dS.png)

Any ideas?